# Liouville's number revisited

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Liouville's Number is defined as $L = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(10^{-n!})$. Does it have other applications than just constructing a transcendental number?

(Personally, I would have defined it (as "Steven's Number" :-)) as binary: $S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^{-n!})$, since each digit can only be "0" or "1": the corresponding power of 2 (instead of 10) included or not. Since according to Cantor most number are transcendental one can conjecture that this is also the case for Steven's Number. Can a proof for this be devised based on the proof for Liouville's number?)

I'm not a mathematician, so please type slowly! :-)

Comment: My understanding is that Liouville's number is of primarily historical importance: it was the first well-known explicit example of a transcendental number.  That's about all you can say about it.

Comment: Steven's Number is *also* a Liouville Number and indeed it is trancendental! Liouville argument proves that all numbers satisfying a certain criteria are transcendental and $L$ is just one example.

Comment: I guess I should have said "Liouville's constant" instead of "Liouville's number".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the number $S$ is also transcendental, for precisely the same reason as $L$: they both have rational approximations that are far too good to hold for an algebraic number. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) for more details.

If the specific number $L$ is useful for anything else, I'm not aware of it. It's really just a simple example, one of many which can be dreamed up, of a number which fails to be algebraic since it defies Liouville's Lemma in diophantine approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Liouville's Number makes it's next appearance in *Making Transcendence Transparent - Edward B. Burger, Robert Tubbs*. The transcendence of $e + L$ is proved. (This might be the end of it's career though).

Comment: $e+L$ is already proven transcendental? Interesting.