# Compute $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k!}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How could the series below be computed ?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k!}}$$
It's not a series from a book, but a series I thought of many times, and I didn't
manage to figure out what I should do here. I'm just curious to know if there are
some known ways for approaching such a series. Thanks!

Comment: I've reverted your edit; I think changing it to just "Compute [the sum]" might attract down-votes, since questions that take the form of commands tend to be frowned upon by some here.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: thanks for your concern! After a while I prefer to delete the explanations I give when I firstly post a question and only want to let the essential part. I think the questions look better with a concise appearance. :). OK, I let this question the way it is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a binary version of [Liouville's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html), one of the first explicitly given numbers to be proved transcendental. I don't think it has any nicer expression than the series itself.

Of course it is easy to *write down* the sum, as a binary fraction!

$$ 1.01000100000000000000000100000..._2 $$

and it is also easy to produce the decimal representation digit by digit -- except for the first few terms, the *first* significant digit of each term comes *after* the *last* nonzero digit of the terms before, so we get

$$ 1.265625059604644775390625000000..._{10} $$

Comment: (+1) Interesting. This is new to me. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I might use this number in my discrete dynamical systems class. It gets closer and closer to zero under the doubling mapping but never quite gets there!

Answer (score 10):

In fact, your series very likely has no better closed-form than that, and its value is transcendental.  This can be explained by the fact that the number is a so-called [*Liouville Number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) — in a sense, it's 'too close' to its rational approximations to be an algebraic number.  For more details on a closely-related number (replacing your $2$ by $10$, have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html (and [Liouville's number revisited](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519/liouvilles-number-revisited) ) — in particular, it turns out that the continued fractions for these numbers have a surprisingly explicit form.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt it can be given in a closed form, but if your interested in very fast converging series that can be given in closed form here are a couple:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{x^{2^n}+1}=\frac{1}{x-1}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n(3^{3^n}+2)}{(x^2)^{3^n}+x^{3^n}+1}=\frac{1}{x-1}$$
$$\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{x^x} \ dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^n}$$

Comment: thanks. It might help in my future studies. (+1)

Comment: @Ethan, do you have any online references, or outline for proofs of these identities?

Comment: The first two I found from playing with geometric series, the third one is called the Sophmore's dream it can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream.

Comment: But that has absolutely nothing to do with the question!